# condition on javascript if json_encode contains a character from a database query

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am creating a restriction of buttons for my page that will be based on database. I could use the json_encode if a cell is == A . 
But I would like to validate if the json result contains a letter A on it.

database : 
| id | Config  | 
| 02| ABCD  |

please see my current code below

on my restriction.php page

```
if($client >= 0){
$data = $con->query("SELECT Config FROM data WHERE id = ".$userid." limit 1;");
$configuration_data = $data->fetch_assoc();
}
echo '<script>window.configuration_data = '.json_encode ($configuration_data).'</script>';
```

on my config.js this code validates only if the result is A but i would like if the cell has a letter A on it

```
if(window.configuration_data.Config == "A"){ 
  $('.Modify').hide();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you limit the content directly from your databse query ?

Comment: @slig36 but he brings config for a specific user. He can be hiding some things and showing other things depending on the content of the config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.configuration_data = {"Config":"ABCD"};
if(window.configuration_data.Config.indexOf('A') > -1) {
  console.log('hide .Modify here')
  //$('.Modify').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if the string contains the "A" character.

```
if(window.configuration_data.Config.indexOf("A") != -1){ 
  $('.Modify').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use mysql LIKE clause, LIKE '%A%'

`$data = $con->query("SELECT Config FROM data WHERE id = ".$userid." AND Config LIKE '%A%' limit 1;");`

This query only return value if Config cell has letter A on value.

Or you can use JavaScript to compare substring like:

```
var string = window.configuration_data.Config,
substring = "A";
string.indexOf(substring) !== -1;`
```

Using search or RexEx you can achive this too.

```
var string = "foo",
    expr = /oo/;
string.search(expr);

var string = "foo",
    expr = /oo/; 
expr.test(string);
```

Comment: my condition is on the javascript so i decided to use the .indexof

Comment: Your use of the `LIKE` is terrible for the database, please read up on how MySQL indexes text before you advise people to use it. Either 'A%' or '%A' are ok, but '%A%' will cause MySQL to perform a full table search.

Comment: What do you suggest? You can make a comment so he can get some help from it. If you ready his question you'll get that that `A` can be in the middle of string stored in database. Is make the query slower but is it forbidden to use? What if I have to search with `%A%` ?